# Compare 2 List<T> to get a List with active players

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, unity3d

I have a little problem: I have a list with all the users that have logged in the game and a list that has all the names of the active players and I make a List with all the players as a `List<T>` (It's a Lists  List).

```
public void CheckNames()
{
    results.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < TC.chatters.viewers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!TotalPlayerNames.Contains(TC.chatters.viewers[i]))
        {
            TotalPlayerNames.Add(TC.chatters.viewers[i]);
            TotalPlayers.Add(new PlayerReal(TC.chatters.viewers[i]));
        }
        if (TotalPlayerNames.Contains(TC.chatters.viewers[i]))
        {
            results.AddRange(TotalPlayers.FindAll(x => x.displayName == TC.chatters.viewers[i]));
            for (int j = 0; j < results.Count; j++)
            {
                results[j].active = true;
            }

        }
    }

    ActivePlayers = results;
    for (int k = 0; k < TotalPlayers.Count; k++)
    {
        bool check = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < TC.chatters.viewers.Length; i++)
        {

            if (TotalPlayers[k].displayName == TC.chatters.viewers[i] && !check)
            {
                TotalPlayers[k].active = true;
                check = true;
            }
            else if (TotalPlayers[k].displayName != TC.chatters.viewers[i] && !check && ((TC.chatters.viewers.Length-1)==i))
            {
                TotalPlayers[k].active = false;
                check = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

There's no problem if I have 100-300 players playing but I DO have a huge problem if 1000-10000 players are playing... any help on this? This method executes each 20 seconds.

Comment: [HashSet vs List performance example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/150750/463206).

Answer (score 3):

Please use conventional naming of properties. `Chatters` instead of `chatters` for example.

Also, why do you use `for` instead of `foreach` if you use index only to get an element of collection? Use `foreach` and your code will be much clearer.

First thing that should come into your mind when you encounter many `Contains` and `!Contains` calls which need to determine if an element should be added into a collection is to use `HashSet`. Use `HashSet<string>` for `TotalPlayerNames` and `TC.Chatters.Viewers`.

Main problem of your code is a lot of repeating loops and duplications like `TC.chatters.viewers[i]`. Please learn programming basics and particularly C# basics.

All your code can be rewritten like:

```
var viewers = TC.Chatters.Viewers;

TotalPlayers.AddRange(viewers.Where(v => TotalPlayerNames.Add(v))
                             .Select(v => new PlayerReal(v)));

var activePlayers = new List<PlayerReal>();
foreach (var player in TotalPlayers)
{
    player.Active = viewers.Contains(player.DisplayName);
    if (player.Active)
        activePlayers.Add(player);
}

ActivePlayers = activePlayers;
```